# Accidentally restore a VirtualBox VM to a snapshot

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, restore, snapshot

I never made a snapshot of my VM before. Accidentally, I restored it from the current state to the original state (the first snapshot it made automatically).

Is there anyway to go back to my LAST state?

I'm using VirtualBox running Win7 on Mac OSX (host)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the **Create Snapshot before restore**?[image: http://cdn5.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/image55.png]

If **yes**, you can restore.

If **no**, then I'm sorry to say **it is gone forever**

Comment: Sad. If you close the virtual machine, but accidentally have the "Restore current snapshot" box checked (which I think is the default), they don't even give that warning. You just discover any virtual hard drives attached to the virtual machine have been meticulously reverted/wiped bit by bit after you reboot the virtual machine. (Either that or it never copies any thing to them at all until after the virtual machine stops without reverting.)